# Storing loops in looped variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, variables, for-loop

I am calculating the buoyancy force of a wing via multiple points. For this I have specific surfaces and air pressure data. What I want to now is storing calculated values in a variable via loop like this:

```
w = 0.7

# air pressure data
pt = np.array([0, -18.63, -80.41, -88.25, 90.21, -95.61])
pb = np.array([-112.28, 34.32, -101.98, -85.31, -3.33, 11.47, 14.71])

#top wing x-pos.
xt = np.array([11, 9.1, 6.85, 4.7, 1.7, 0.6, 1.9])
#bottom wing x-pos. 
xb = np.array([2.85,0.8, 0.85, 2.5, 4.225, 6.7, 9.025, 11])

#top wing y-pos.
yt = np.array([1, 2.1, 3.05, 3.8, 3.7, 2.1, 1])
#bottom wing y-pos. 
yb = np.array([4.05, 3, 1.55, 0.95, 1.125, 1.3, 1.225,1])


for i in range(0,5):
    at[i] = sqrt( (xt[i] - xt[i+1]) ** 2 + (yt[i] - yt[i+1]) **2 ) * w
    ab[i] = sqrt( (xb[i] - xb[i+1]) ** 2 + (yb[i] - yb[i+1]) **2 ) * w
```

On the left it should create multiple variables like these:

```
at0 = ...
 :
 :
at5 = ... 

ab0 = ...
 :
 :
ab5 = ...
```

and on the right it adresses the stored numbers in the `np.array()`s

This gives this error though: `NameError: name 'at' is not defined`
and afterwards continue like this:

```
for x in range(0,5):
    Ft = sum( at[x] * pt[x] )
    Fb = sum( ab[x] * pb[x] )
```

Until now I tried to do it with dictionaries, loops given in one line... But it doesn't work.

By the way: Does it matter whether I use `np.sum()` and `np.sqrt()` instead of using `sum()` and `sqrt()`?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What doesn't work? It would help if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an adequate problem statement. Please elaborate.

Comment: Please show a code snippet that shows the problem and the full traceback that results from that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variable `at` before you try to make assignments to it. You're getting the error because the variable doesn't exist. If you just need a simple list, you need `at = []` before your loop.

Then, in your loop, instead of directly assigning a given index, you can just use `at.append(<computation>)`

Comment: There are other iterable types that might be more appropriate depending on the situation.